# Return type error if element label passed does not exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component which takes in three props; children(react elements), index and label. When index is passed, it should return the child element at that particular index. and when label is passed, it returns the element with that label. I would like to modify my types to return a type error if one passes a label which is not in the elements, ie label="Four", typescript should be able to catch that, since that label is not part of the elements.

```
type IComp = {
  children: React.ReactElement[],} &(
  | {

    index:number,
    label: never,
  }
  | {
    label: string,
    index:never,
  }
)

function Comp(props:IComp) {
return (
<div >
          {props.children.map((item) => {

            return (
              <button><button>
            )

          })}

      </div>
)
}


function Main() {
  return (
      <Comp label={"four"}> //This should show a type error
        <div label={"One"}>
             <p>One</p>
           </div>
        </div>
          <div label={"Two"}>
             <p>Two</p>
           </div>
            <div label={"Three"}>
              <p>Three</p>
            </div>
      </Comp>
    
  );
}

export Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a union:

```
type IComp = {
  children: React.ReactElement[],} &(
  | {

    index:number,
    label: never,
  }
  | {
    label: 'One' | 'Two' | 'Three',
    index:never,
  }
)
```

Comment: What if the labels get changed or become more?

Comment: Where are they sourced from? Are they known ahead of time, or are you expecting it to inspect the JSX and know from that?

Comment: they are added whenever a new div is created.

Comment: Hmmm. Give me some time to think about -- generally using nested JSX elements to infer types can be tricky, bare with me.

Comment: Have come to the conclusion you simply cannot infer childrens props with typescript. You can restrict it such that it must have a certain prop, but you cant collate them -- its a TS shortfall.

Comment: However, I think what you are trying to do is quite odd and looks to me like an architectural flaw. But I'd need more context on what you are trying to achieve to help. Currently your Compo component just loads a button for each child. Typically you wouldn't compose by looping over the children, you'd instead create a new component that represents each child and that would do the logic.